# referrerNotAllowedMapError only in IE11

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a site where the map loads fine everywhere but IE11 (Edge and IE10 are both fine). Actually it loads for a second before being replaced with "Sorry, something went wrong" and in the console it says the error is `referrerNotAllowedMapError`.

The js code for the page is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {

    var styles =  [
    ];

    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
      {name: 'Styled Map'});

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
      }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

    var image = '/assets/img/marker.png';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      title: 'Title',
      icon: image
    });

    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
    marker.setMap(map);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Why would the map be fine in other browsers, but not IE11?

Comment: Check the value of windows.location.href in your application and compare it with a restriction that you have for an API key.

Comment: Sorry, not sure where should I be checking for the value of `windows.location.href`.

Comment: In your JavaScript code. Add something like alert(window.location.href); when you load the map and check this value.

Comment: I've got http referrers restriction in place but under *Accept requests from…* I've got `*.mydomain.com/*`.